# Correct way to show an image that comes from a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have a controller that loads an image file:

```
    //
    // GET: /MyController/Image/id
    public ActionResult Image(string id)
    {
        var dir = @"C:\Temp\Images";
        var path = Path.Combine(dir, id + ".png");
        return File(path, "image/png");
    }
```

In a separate view from action `MyController/Page/id` I have hastily hashed up some html to show the image:

```
<img src="../image/@Model.Name" />
```

And then also with a link:

```
<a href="../image/@Model.Name">
  <img src="../image/@Model.Name" />
</a>
```

It works, but I am looking for a better way using `@Html` so resharper can help with navigation and validation, for the two above. I've tried this:

```
@Html.RenderAction("Image", "MyController", new { id = Model.Name })
```

But this doesn't compile, it says `Expression must return a value to render`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just looking for `Url.Action()`, which returns an URL to an Action:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Image", "ImageController", new { id = Model.ImageID })" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Url.Action()` in the src attribute

```
 <img src='@Url.Action("Image", "ImageController", new { imageId = Model.Id })' alt='MyImage' />
```