# NAS to serve images in a web app MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, nas

I have a Nas that I am storing images to in a web app, but now I need to retrieve them. I have the image tag showing :

```
 <img src="file://///06imagestore\RSVP\20141105_074252.jpg" width="960">
```

The image does not show, but when I right click in firefox and lookup image info, the picture shows up in the dialog, but not on the site.  Is there something I am doing wrong here?  I am using MVC 4.

For clarification this is the process: 
The web app is on a shared virtual server.  The amount of space available on the server cannot be inundated with images,  the solution was to save the path to a database, and the image to a NAS in the network. I cannot save the image to the original server, because eventually we will have too many images for the server we are running the program / web app on.

The process is to get the path back from the database, (the one that points to the NAS) and use it to grab the picture.

I think I am just missing something like a setting, but I do not know I am reaching out to see if anyone from the group has had experience doing this sort of thing?  I have been stumped for several hours.

Comment: prefer to use 

An absolute URL - points to another web site (like src="http://www.example.com/image.gif") OR 
A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like src="image.gif")

Comment: Yes I would too, but that is not an option. The image is stored on a NAS

Comment: Looks like I phrased my question wrong when I initially asked here.  There is a solution for this in stackoverflow that I did not realize [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133664/reading-streams-from-image-on-a-web-page-in-asp-net)

Comment: also check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/19728199/991513

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an action that handles the image return via a standard web request:

For example

```
public FileResult Image(string path)
{
    // get the image byte stream
    var file = File.OpenRead("NAS_DRIVE" + path)
    var mime = // work out the mime type based on extentsion (file.Extension)
    return new FileResult(file, mime);
}
```

Then in your view use something like

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Home", "Image", new {path = '06imagestore\RSVP\20141105_074252.jpg')" width="960">
```

You might want to look at caching the file results too if there are going to be many different requests for the same image, just to speed things up.

Comment: Caching is not a bad idea. I will look into that.